# How to increment potion effects?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to figure out how to make it so that, instead of giving a new potion effect, I could add to the previous ones, i.e. 2 + 3 = 5.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could start a scoreboard, something called `effectLevel` for example. You could then run a series of command blocks that gives all players with `effectLevel` score 1, level 2 effect. This is just a brainstorm idea from me, as I'm not familiar with scoreboard commands, but I believe that would work.